# How to get woocommerce cart products in custom plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating a plugin. i want to display woocommerce cart. I have tried `WC()->cart->get_cart()`
But its display this error. `Fatal error: Call to undefined function WC()`.

Comment: Why don't you use the Widget ..Something like if woocommmerce is installed then and then this widget will be called .

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner i want to create own widget.

Comment: Then you need to add woocommerce file to use it with condition that if plugin is activated or not :
`if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) { 

//You code goes here ....

}`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably calling the function to early,use can use wp_loaded hook

```
add_action('wp_loaded', array( $this, 'myfunction')); 
//if not in class ('wp_loaded', 'myfunction')

function myfunction(){

 $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `global $woocommerce;` instead of `WC()`. your final code will be:

```
global $woocommerce;
$cart = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
```